# IntelliJ rename java package and occurances?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have intelliJ already setup to "compact empty middle packages"

When I do refactor -> rename, the only dialog will only actually rename the directory (even when I have it search for occurances), resulting in my code that uses the package throughout the project, still using the original name.

I'm sure there used to be a way to "rename package" and not just the directory, did the mechanism for this change? I really need to rename my package.

Please don't mark this as a duplicate, because the other places I see this being asked, the solution is to first "compact empty middle packages" - which I have already done... and I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Do you perform the rename in the folder view or in the code itself?

Comment: @MrMister I right clicked to folder in project view, and then went to refactor -> rename, am I supposed to do it a different way?

Comment: What IDE version do you use? Running "Refactor -> Rename" on compacted package shows dialog with "Rename package"/ "Rename directory" options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to open a class that is in that package, then right click on the `package xyz.abc` line (should be the first line in that file) and choose Refactor -> Rename from the context menu.